# Python: Import could not be resolved

Tags: python, python-3.x

These are the imports I am trying to import:

```
import json
import os
import re
import uuid

from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth import jwt, crypt
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Import "google.auth.transport.requests" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImport)
Import "google.oauth2" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImport)
Import "google.auth" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImport)
```

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Comment: Did you install google modules?

Comment: You mean the google cloud sdk? @matszwecja

Comment: No, I mean `pip install ...`

Comment: @matszwecja I don't think so what modules do I need?

Comment: Thanks it where the google modules! @matszwecja